# Tor'ing through dual router network

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

I have a two router setup at home. The master router handles the incoming DSL connection and DHCP settings, and the second router is used as a wireless extender. My desktop also connects via the second router by means of a LAN cable. DHCP is switched off on the second router.

Will using TOR via the second router though the master compromise on anonymity? Is there anything else I should consider doing with the set up in order to make browsing more secure?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that setup. It's encrypted before it hits your first router on the way out, and not decrypted until it reaches your computer on the way back in. Through your routers its just encrypted data streams.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely fine, I'm using such a configuration myself : one for incoming ISP link, and a Raspberry Pi 2 for Tor. Just one "pain-in-the-ass" in this setup is COMPLETELY DISABLE UPnP, or some leaks will occur in applications and sometimes Tor can try to map something to itself. I've solved this by compiling Tor by hand without any UPnP support AND disabling UPnP on the outbound router. In my case Tor router has same 192.168.X.Y IP in the same network, so maybe this was an issue, but verifying a tcpdump after the actions I've told you : no attempts to bypass tor router were made. All the port mappings are made statically to statical internal IP's of my home lan.